# R ggplot2: Weird x axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I have a question concerning a plot. I have two datatables with the exact same type and structure.

```
> dput(test_ok_score_per_week)

structure(list(week = structure(c(14851, 14858, 14865, 14872, 
14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 14928, 14935, 
14942, 14949, 14956, 14963, 14970, 14977, 14984, 14991, 14998, 
15005, 15012, 15019, 15026, 15033, 15040, 15047, 15054, 15061, 
15068, 15075, 15082, 15089, 15096, 15103, 15110, 15117, 15124, 
15131, 15138, 15145, 15152, 15159, 15166, 15173, 15180, 15187, 
15194, 15201, 15208, 15215, 15222, 15229, 15236, 15243, 15250, 
15257, 15264, 15271, 15278, 15285, 15292, 15299, 15306, 15313, 
15320, 15327, 15334, 15341, 15348, 15355, 15362, 15369, 15376, 
15383, 15390, 15397, 15404, 15411, 15418, 15425, 15432, 15439, 
15446, 15453, 15460, 15467, 15474, 15481, 15488, 15495, 15502, 
15509, 15516, 15523, 15530, 15537, 15544, 15551, 15558, 15565, 
15572, 15579, 15586, 15593, 15600, 15607), class = "Date"), sscore = c(-0.0271358645656252, 
-0.037443580400772, -0.0249193225740284, -0.0347116914149199, 
-0.04397195623097, -0.0501096599291317, -0.0562956802871331, 
-0.0549726569024243, -0.0362898482562824, -0.036058729876546, 
-0.041530462181682, -0.0269288251170689, -0.0275249418536023, 
-0.0425459083333832, -0.0490438031842451, -0.0335759180098395, 
-0.0324032084061856, -0.0340582689452737, -0.0149952176625443, 
-0.0436057657630004, -0.0443365969917196, -0.032299380149188, 
-0.0183893625370764, -0.0358883187348227, -0.0253667676700943, 
-0.0231871990092394, -0.0388525539048718, -0.0420056500489763, 
-0.0580875231638775, -0.0258965946457731, -0.0331923364479837, 
-0.0331652877847282, -0.0355923426011811, -0.0490108390902244, 
-0.038584115179578, -0.036757958377633, -0.0201843618058785, 
-0.0403748675373667, -0.0439202530880046, -0.0326769632966276, 
-0.0391403797680461, -0.0488800462977921, -0.0392870714538481, 
-0.0305464832366949, -0.0194734982401969, -0.0369240824452019, 
-0.046667850362033, -0.0555569121289979, -0.0651735779321786, 
-0.0406515199207789, -0.0431388317033185, -0.0348516612281556, 
-0.0457609714371388, -0.0493196752878116, -0.0601316474074199, 
-0.0704452681201514, -0.0427066937741966, -0.0474308621447724, 
-0.0518832819764233, -0.0549398158136734, -0.0359792801727264, 
-0.0570364984494953, -0.0298260589993722, -0.0357518787648021, 
-0.0371472787805426, -0.0278988296647244, -0.0395376607956671, 
-0.0451045722237352, -0.0453820371270336, -0.0738453350009387, 
-0.0516903118084151, -0.0578891006219142, -0.0535760268505219, 
-0.0451023230343747, -0.0607208338304486, -0.0595978187091988, 
-0.0388973793756239, -0.0347397643296738, -0.0386428681880737, 
-0.0365648757158644, -0.029014696012485, -0.0152477234425284, 
-0.0421959693996071, -0.0409836329546548, -0.024063587756784, 
-0.0178120714049416, -0.0447750644035274, -0.0236156700267302, 
-0.0410306954195238, -0.0493233719224717, -0.0439222633848824, 
-0.0323923585051494, -0.0542526420862045, -0.0431570532237916, 
-0.0563737821579257, -0.0357569185056218, -0.0453982981166643, 
-0.0453778322792568, -0.0425245156245882, -0.0441659122242861, 
-0.0364353492271389, -0.0495679367162942, -0.0318880748803625, 
-0.0120020011925775, -0.0706190386564516, -0.0192665807147596, 
-0.0523104405204151, -0.041161155934461, -0.0118519557353576)), row.names = c(NA, 
-109L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000017523d1ded0>)


> dput(test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week)

structure(list(week = structure(c(18379, 18386, 18393, 18400, 
18407, 18414, 18421, 18428, 18435, 18442, 18449, 18456, 18463, 
18470, 18477, 18484, 18491, 18498, 18505, 18512, 18519, 18526, 
18533, 18540, 18547, 18554, 18561, 18568, 18575, 18582, 18589, 
18596, 18603, 18610, 18617, 18624, 18631, 18638, 18645, 18652, 
18659, 18666, 18673, 18680, 18687, 18694, 18701, 18708, 18715, 
18722, 18729, 18736, 18743, 18750, 18757, 18764, 18771, 18778, 
18785, 18792, 18799, 18806, 18813, 18820, 18827, 18834, 18841, 
18848, 18855, 18862, 18869, 18876, 18883, 18890, 18897, 18904, 
18911, 18918, 18925, 18932, 18939, 18946, 18953, 18960, 18967, 
18974, 18981, 18988, 18995, 19002, 19009, 19016, 19023, 19030, 
19037, 19044, 19051, 19058, 19065, 19072, 19079, 19086, 19093, 
19100, 19107, 19114, 19121, 19128, 19135, 19142), class = "Date"), 
    sscore = c(-0.0986769230769231, -0.0283960338802917, -0.0363608945035135, 
    -0.0528381160499204, -0.0549262067339719, -0.0209278811491654, 
    -0.0491714266870658, -0.0532069905220855, -0.0561343381423505, 
    -0.0317928650171208, -0.0238342583982518, -0.0604882470833225, 
    -0.02529394430874, -0.0530791367431541, -0.0184513424316339, 
    -0.0185608180521884, -0.0345724115118704, -0.0437165716274871, 
    -0.0575686775823271, -0.0265453239960545, -0.0519434486098939, 
    -0.048156661409469, -0.0270179808617657, -0.0329184524967364, 
    -0.0448931930192764, -0.0290217551817534, -0.0385034990454125, 
    -0.0288086746833992, -0.0286389542917401, -0.0256667198691171, 
    -0.0364626314304105, -0.0312740494792047, -0.014004425584609, 
    -0.0465972055930389, -0.0512269924161891, -0.0384905452781594, 
    -0.0483592742458285, -0.0405035204572515, -0.0371672390232625, 
    -0.0547459854688676, -0.0408300987215065, -0.0227150650768663, 
    -0.0375129258116499, -0.0161056835909683, -0.0525592911089886, 
    -0.0369853291524879, -0.0382602688217775, -0.0416891764748201, 
    -0.0709903523938417, -0.0566143046460412, -0.0349690141669773, 
    -0.0489528672196799, -0.0611805194349824, -0.0243121116071908, 
    -0.0397066712200139, -0.0425021728800334, -0.0250748186273967, 
    -0.0187869530564284, -0.0243639744874882, -0.0493452515232763, 
    -0.0354670177389483, -0.0094132430385961, -0.0339373520682526, 
    -0.0716701479224177, -0.00916938835578756, -0.0513389955369511, 
    -0.0309089809954752, -0.0351378461392007, -0.0177431325315011, 
    -0.0256987948428901, -0.0369904218696866, -0.0286582020369608, 
    -0.00955705200997361, -0.059367299151086, -0.0390818585167929, 
    -0.0587766011224465, -0.0256168015673999, -0.0516395484641526, 
    -0.0452655837017515, -0.0316173817750227, -0.0382418361500235, 
    -0.0202842221300527, -0.0126035989079273, -0.0563411072619509, 
    -0.0429824541797429, -0.0506041835794309, -0.0395476843700854, 
    -0.0303819390820148, -0.0520374410842234, -0.0398105399023013, 
    -0.0456786782721091, -0.0626092739432066, -0.0230247630284049, 
    -0.0454614479953003, -0.0396632064932559, -0.0651135145642635, 
    -0.0493833007536216, -0.0476300908767504, -0.0343312087306037, 
    -0.0639782552747063, -0.045457458720986, -0.0541783315220931, 
    -0.0744762672994299, -0.0493042164219308, -0.0574169736736824, 
    -0.0350462089024535, -0.0611996342089181, -0.0459144417115672, 
    -0.0381642037811964, -0.0930032298325723)), row.names = c(NA, 
-110L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000017523d1ded0>)
```

**I plotted them as follows:**

**The plot for test_ok_score_per_week:**

```
# test_ok_score_per_week$week as.Date-Format

test_ok_score_per_week$week <- as.Date(test_ok_score_per_week$week, format = "%d-%m-%y")

#only every fifth week on x axis labels --> better visibility

every_fifth_week <- test_ok_score_per_week$week[seq(1, nrow(test_ok_score_per_week), by = 5)]

# Ensure the specific date is included

specific_date <- as.Date("12-09-2011", format = "%d-%m-%Y")
if(!(specific_date %in% every_fifth_week)) {
  every_fifth_week <- sort(c(every_fifth_week, specific_date))
}

# Find the position of the specific date

specific_date_position <- which(every_fifth_week == specific_date)

# Remove the date that follows the specific date

if(specific_date_position < length(every_fifth_week)) {
  every_fifth_week <- every_fifth_week[-(specific_date_position + 1)]
}

# Plotting data
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test_ok_score_per_week, aes(x = week, y = sscore)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = subset(test_ok_score_per_week, week == specific_date), aes(x = week, y = sscore), colour = "red", size = 3) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = every_fifth_week, date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y") +
  labs(x = "startdate of each week (Monday)", y = "score") +
  ggtitle("title") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

**and the plot for test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week:**

```
# test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week$week as.Date-Format

test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week$week <- as.Date(test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week$week, format = "%d-%m-%y")

#only every fifth week on x axis labels --> better visibility

every_fifth_week <- test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week$week[seq(1, nrow(test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week), by = 5)]

# Ensure the specific date is included

specific_date <- as.Date("24-05-2021", format = "%d-%m-%Y")
if(!(specific_date %in% every_fifth_week)) {
  every_fifth_week <- sort(c(every_fifth_week, specific_date))
}

# Find the position of the specific date

specific_date_position <- which(every_fifth_week == specific_date)

# Remove the date that follows the specific date

if(specific_date_position < length(every_fifth_week)) {
  every_fifth_week <- every_fifth_week[-(specific_date_position + 1)]
}

# Plotting data
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week, aes(x = week, y = sscore)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = subset(test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week, week == specific_date), aes(x = week, y = sscore), colour = "red", size = 3) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = every_fifth_week, date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y") +
  labs(x = "week", y = "score") +
  ggtitle("title: weird x axis labels") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

T**hese codes generate these two plots (the first one is from test_ok_score_per_week):**

[image]

and

[image]

Why do these two plots look different, respectively: Why has the plot of the datatable test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week this weird fault on the x axis labels?

Answer (score 0):

The five-weeks grid is readily obtained with the `date_breaks` argument. Taking `test_not_ok_test_not_ok_score_per_week` as example:

```
## ... +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '5 weeks',
               date_minor_breaks = '1 week',
               limits = as.Date(c('2020-04-27', '2022-05-30')) +
## ...
```